# Как сохранить рисунок matplotlib через ipywidgets.Button, при этом рисунок меняется с помощью interact

Tags: python, виджет, matplotlib

Есть interact, который запускает функцию EDS c параметрами, ползунками меняются параметры, соответственно меняется график. Хочу сделать кнопку которая бы сохраняла график с выбранными параметрами. Если объявить функцию
кнопки внутри EDS, то вроде как работает, только сохраняются все графики которые перебирались ползунками, а мне надо только один. Подскажите, как настроить кнопку, чтобы один раз нажал и сохранил один нужный график. Может какой-то декоратор хитрый сделать, типа логгера? Но я не понимаю как.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets

def save_plot(plt, d, B, n,fmt='png'):
    name = 'EDS_d{}_B{}_n1e{}'.format(d,B,n)
    plt.savefig('{}.{}'.format(name, fmt), fmt='png')

def EDS(d, B, n):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,3))
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    n1=1*10**n
    d1=d*10**(-3)
    EDSH=(I*B)/(e*n1*d1)
    ax.plot(I, EDSH)
    ax.set_ylim(0)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_ylabel('E (V)')
    ax.set_xlabel('I (A)')
    ax.text(0.05, 0.7, 'd = {}(mm)\nB = {}(T)\nn = 10^{}(m^3)'.format(d, 
    B, n), fontsize=12, transform=ax.transAxes)
    def on_button_clicked(Event):
        save_plot(fig, d, B, n,fmt='png')
        print('Plot saved in EDS_d{}_B{}_n1e{}.png'.format(d,B,n))
    button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

I = np.arange(15*10**(-3), 50*10**(-3), 1*10**(-3))
e = 1.6*10**(-19)

interact(EDS, d = (1, 2, 0.1),n = (16, 24, 1),B = (0.16, 0.35, 0.01))
button = widgets.Button(description="Save plot")
display(button)
```

Comment: можно interact_manual использовать, чтобы функция только по нажатию на кнопку работала (без автоматических обновлений, пока вы ползунки туда/сюда таскаете).

Comment: тот же самый эффект, после нажатия на кнопку все равно будет сохранение всех пройденных параметров(

Comment: хотя частично решает проблему, но все равно, зависит от количества запусков функции

Comment: попробуйте *минимальный* но полный пример кода создать, который демонстрирует проблему [mcve]. К примеру, вот [код, который демонстрирует, что одно нажатие кнопки соответствует одному вызову функции и только текущее значение параметра отображается](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/zed/jupyter-notebooks/master?filepath=ipynb%2Finteract-manual.ipynb)